# How to click on vimeo player full screen on document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo-api

I am trying to click on vimeo player fullscreen on document ready.
How can I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.fullscreen-icon')[0].click(function () {
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/3873878" width="320" height="240" webkitallowfullscreen
        mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot access elements inside iFrame until your parent page & iFrame has same domain.

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: Change the iframe size from `width="320" height="240"` to max possible `(100vh) or 100%` on `document.ready` . You can access iFrame element properties from parent code but, not its inside elements.

Comment: iframes size is not increasing with 100%.

Comment: With `$("iframe").style.width = "100%"` i'm able to cover full screen. Make sure there are no parent element with fixed height/width which are restricting iframe size. If, yes then you can use `position : absolute`.

Comment: not working for me.. can you please edit this code?

Answer (score 1):

But, the problem is document ready will get triggered before iFrame is ready. Since, the parent documents get ready first & triggers the function.

```js
function reszie() {
            $("iframe")[0].style.height = "100vh"
   $("iframe")[0].style.width = "100%";
      $("button")[0].style.display = "none";
        };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="reszie()">Resize<button>
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/3873878" style="height:128px;width:256px;" webkitallowfullscreen
        mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```